# Delete Composite unique key [ applied on 3 fields combinely ]

Tags: mysql, composite-key

In MySQL, I've create a unique composite key, based on 3 columns.

How can I delete this unique key constraint without deleting the entire table?

Answer (score -1):

I found an answer and it worked

```
SHOW INDEX table_name
```

Then find out the constraint from "key_name" which you want to drop.

This "key_name" will be as "`arbitrary_index_name`" for composite keys.

Then use this DROP query

```
DROP INDEX arbitrary_index_name ON table_name
```

Comment: A question which you answered yourself in 11 minutes... probably is not fit for Stack Overflow. This type of info is available on most tutorials ;)

Comment: Dear @Frazz , Everyone may not be as intelligent as you are.. I request you to ATLEAST not to demotivate the young bees if you can not help them.. Heartily thank you for SUGGESTIONS .. :)